# a href onclick not working in windows phone cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8.1

I have used winstore-jscompat.js for js fix. below code generate sub categories.
But it doesnt call   parseSubCategory function.

```
            $.each(category.sub_categories, function(index2, subcategory) {
                   var subCatName = subcategory.name;
                   $("#test-listview" + index).append('<li><a onclick=\"parseSubCategory(' + subcategory.id + ',\'' + subCatName + '\');\" href="#product_List">' + subcategory.name + '</a></li>');

             });
```

Edit:

This is working fine on ios and android but not in windows mobile phone

Comment: I'd suggest some debugging tool for you to use like jshybugger, now it's like reading tea leaves...

Comment: Works ok for me, http://jsfiddle.net/dg1ewoh9/, check your subroutine parseSubCategory

Comment: This code works perfectly on android and ios, my problem is, this is  not working on Windows phone.

Comment: Same problem for me: seems like href don't work on WP

Comment: @Starnutoditopo I have posted a answer for the issue. It works for me.

Comment: @Susitha: thanks for your reply and your answer! In my case, it turned out to be some silly mistake in some other JS code, that caused this strange behavior as side effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue happened because of pulling in potentially unsafe content from an external sources. We can modify jquery source and ignore this. I have found the solutions here.

https://www.incloud.de/2012/08/windows-8-using-jquery-for-app-development/

It works for me.

Comment: Inserting `MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction` before every single onclick event is not realistic for big apps. Is there a more reasonable solution? No onclick events work at all, this is very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Customize the content security policy in the meta tag:

```
http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
```

As needed. Add **unsafe-inline** to `default-src` to enable inline JavaScript.

For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521

Comment: The unsafe-inline trick works for static content, but not for dynamically created buttons and stuff (using jquery). Any ideas why this happens? It worked with the WP8 platform, not anymore with the Windows platform (from Cordova). Thanks.