# Javascript dynamic anchor tag onclick event failing in cordova windows phone

Tags: angularjs, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have added dynamic anchor tag to open a link in browser(in-app browser) its not working in Windows Phone but its working correctly in IOS and Andriod the issue with Windows phone is onclick becomes x-onclick. How can I fix this issue please suggest I am using Visuval Studio 2015 with Cordova tools with Update 9 and the cordova version is 6.1.1

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35497091/853295

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a href onclick not working in windows phone cordova app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735325/a-href-onclick-not-working-in-windows-phone-cordova-app)

Comment: Thanks for your responce @garethb. By carefully investigating I understand that windows phone does not support in-line JavaScript. So I replaced onclick event with href="https://www.website.com" to open a link using in-app browser plugin. This worked for me.

Comment: Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
        For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521 add meta tag http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *"

Comment: Any ideas why onclick events from static buttons do work but not those from dynamically created buttons using jQuery? Thanks.